# Can Galders Tower be summoned to trap another creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can [*Galder's Tower*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/galders-tower) be summoned to trap another creature? If you cast the spell at 3rd level and choose a place within 30 feet to create a 100 square-foot tower that is 2 stories tall and there is a creature within that area, could that creature become trapped within it?

If the creature being trapped is on the ground, would the caster be able to pick which floor they are on?

Answer (score 5):

#### The spell isn't intended to be used in combat, so it's up to the DM.

With a casting time of 10 minutes, we are usually not going to see this come up in combat, unless we are a Chronurgy Wizard using Arcane Abeyance:

> When you cast a spell using a spell slot of 4th level or lower, you can condense the spell’s magic into a mote. The spell is frozen in time at the moment of casting and held within a gray bead for 1 hour. This bead is a Tiny object with AC 15 and 1 hit point, and it is immune to poison and psychic damage. When the duration ends, or if the bead is destroyed, it vanishes in a flash of light, and the spell is lost.
>
> A creature holding the bead can use its action to release the spell within, whereupon the bead disappears. The spell uses your spell attack bonus and save DC, and the spell treats the creature who released it as the caster for all other purposes.

This feature allows a wizard to create a Galder's Tower grenade. We must observe that *the spell description gives us no indication as to what happens in this situation because it is generally assumed we aren't casting it in battle*. So the DM is going to have to make a ruling.

Personally, I would rule that the creature is harmlessly shunted outside the tower area, based on how the spell *wall of stone* functions:

> If the wall cuts through a creature's space when it appears, the creature is pushed to one side of the wall (your choice).

Comment: @Aydens I guess. There are any number of reasonable rulings here, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov fair enough lol, this is so weird

Answer (score 0):

### Possibly

The creature would have to not be alerted to the changing area since the spell takes 10 minutes to cast, as per the description.

Then it's a question of the means by which the tower is conjured into existence. Does it materialize? Do pieces of building material converge upon the site and physically build the tower? Does it rise out of the ground?

The spell could potentially be used this way. Ask your DM.